# Can I synchronize Bookmarks in Chrome using Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I am on another PC and I need to access to bookmarks stored in Firefox Sync profile using Chrome. Is it possible? Can I access to Firefox Sync with tools other than Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Firefox Sync FAQ:

> We currently support Weave Sync for
>   **Firefox** on Windows, Mac and Linux on
>   the desktop, and Maemo on mobile
>   devices.

So Chrome is not supported, but you can use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/). Xmarks can [synchronize](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1749) your bookmarks, passwords, and open tabs across both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, due to this feature I switched back to Xmarks, again. :)